# border between children using selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

What's the typical way to add a border between children of different elements in a div?

In the following example, there should be borders between p,div and div,img.

```
<div id="list">
    <p>child 1</p>
    <div>child 2</div>
    <img src="">
</div>
```

If all the children were `div`, `#list > div~div { border-top: 1px solid black }` would be sufficient, but with different elements, this seems impractical. I attempted `#list > ̃ { border-top: 1px solid black }` with no success. However, `#list > :not(:first-child) { border-top: 1px solid black }` did work. While it's a working solution, I was wondering if there was a better way?

Comment: You need a border style for the border to appear.

Comment: @AndyG I simplified the border definition as it's not very relevant, but since you insist I've added that.

Comment: I went for `#list > :first-element~*`, as it seems to be the simplest one.

Comment: Don't attempt to "simplify" your code into something invalid. You are not helping readers by doing so. Just write down your actual code. This applies not just to your border declaration but also your selectors (which as I'm sure you know *are* relevant to your question): `#list > ̃` and `#list > :not(:first-element)`, both of which are equally nonsensical and there's no way they could possibly work. (Sure, someone like me could *guess* that you really meant the latter to be `#list > :not(:first-child)`, but it's not at all clear to me what `#list > ̃` is supposed to represent.)

Comment: @BoltClock `:first-element` was a typo; `:first-child` was indeed intended. I'm not too familiar with selectors, but `> :first-child` and `> *:first-child` are equivalent, so I thought `> ~` and `> *~*` were equivalent. (They were not.) I was mostly curious about the selectors, so I deemed the border declaration irrelevant, but I see your point.

Comment: @Frank Vel: You know what? I think your take on `> ~` and `> *~*` would make for an interesting, separate question.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your expectation of the final layout. Firstly, I assume you want the elements inside #list to be horizontally aligned. I use a flexbox for that in my code below.

You can define a border at the right of the elements except for the last one:

```css
#list {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#list>*:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: thick solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="list">
  <p>child 1</p>
  <div>child 2</div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50">
</div>
```

However, if you need to use margins for specific elements, the borders may no longer be aligned vertically.

```css
#list {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#list>*:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: thick solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="list">
  <p style="margin: 1em;">child 1</p>
  <div>child 2</div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50">
</div>
<div id="list">
  <p>child 1</p>
  <div>child 2</div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50">
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't this just a *really* roundabout way of saying "no, there is no better way than applying a border to all but the first/last child"? Also, why would you assume the asker wants the elements laid out horizontally when their examples include border-top declarations, not border-right?

Answer (score 1):

```
#list :not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This shoud work aswell

```
#list * {
 border: 1px solid red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/84djw33j/2/

Comment: I want a single border between each element, your solution would add two borders (one from each element).

Comment: @FrankVel then add `border-bottom: 0;` to the style.

Comment: you could add a border-top and a border-bottom on the element in the middle of your parent element. Tho this would only work, if there are only three child elements

Comment: @zgood I want the border *between* the elements. In this solution the first child would still have a top border, so it should not be selected

Answer (score -2):

Try using  :first-of-type, :last-of-type, and :only-of-type pseudo-selectors Here's a useful [link](http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/complex-selectors/)

Comment: The link is just as useless as your answer.